# How could I replace variadic template expansion with macro in c++

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-templates, variadic-macros

I've got the following code:

```
template<typename... Args> constexpr static const inline int sc(Args&&... args)
{
    return scanf(_hidden::fmt< decltype(args+0)... >::result::data,
                 _hidden::link<decltype(&args),decltype(args+0)>({&args,args}).data...);
}
```

At least g++ compiler without -O3 flag compiles it to function call, ignoring inline parameter. How could I replace such complicated variadic expansion with macro or anything else, what would compile to single scanf call without extra functions using any compiler set?
Just academic interest, in real cases -O3 flag does everything

Comment: Have you tried link-time optimizations like `-flto` and `-fwhole-program`? Also, can you tell us what the second parameter is supposed to do?

Comment: Why? I/O will dominate your function call many times over.

Comment: @black , the question is not about compiler options, but about other ways of implementation. As I mentioned, I've already could compile it with -O3 and there will be no extra function call.
Second and other arguments are the selectors between &args and args depending on type. `sc(i,s)` works as `scanf("%i%s",&i,s)`, for example.

Comment: @n.m. , for academic interest, I just want to get better understanding of variadic macros and functions to make a better code in future

Comment: Sorry I missed your last statement. I get your interest, but do notice that macros will not make your code any better, just worse.

Comment: When did scanf become constexpr? In the land of undefined behaviour, it is legal for the compiler to make demons fly out of your nose.